# How to create a new column from a data frame, but using on a piece of data from existing column

Tags: r

Basically, I have a data frame called `top100_retailers`. It has a column named `Headquarter` that contains the city, state(For example: `Bentonville, Ark.`). I want to create 2 new columns called `City` and `State`. How do I only take the city information and assign it to the new `City` column and only take the state information and assign it to the new "State" column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do this with `separate` from `tidyr`

```
library(tidyr)
top100_retailers <- separate(top100_retailers, Headquarter, into = c("City", "State"))
```

If we want to keep the 'Headquarter' column as well, use the `remove = FALSE` argument as it is by default `TRUE`.

Comment: Should this automatically create the new columns "City" and "State" for the data frame?

Comment: @user6794408  The `separate` will automaticaly find the delimiter, in this case the `,` and create the two columns.  We have to provide the names of the new columns i.e. `City` and `State`